# Дополнительный код в Python

Tags: python

Необходимо обрабатывать `WAV`файл. Данные, хранящиеся в нем представлены в прямом коде, `Python` работает с бинарными данными в дополнительном коде. 
Так выглядит синус, считанный из WAV файла и отображенный с помощью `Matplotlib`. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в Python преобразовать данные из прямого кода в дополнительный?

Comment: Можете уточнить что значит прямой и дополнительный код?

Comment: @MaxU https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python ?

Comment: Было бы неплохо привести в вопросе несколько входных и выходных значений...

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы читаете данные из файла.

Comment: Данные в файле хранятся в бинарном виде, а как вы уже их проинтерпретируете - это уже другой вопрос. Отрицательные числа как правило хранятся в дополнительном коде. Если прочитать массив знаковых чисел как массив как массив беззнаковых, то отрицательные числа будут проинтерпретированы как большие большие положительные. Проблема не в том как работает Python с числами, а в том что вы не так прочитали массив.

Comment: `dtype=np.int16`?